# Fat Free: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so'

Tags: php, linux, imagick, fat-free-framework

Having this `Fat Free` error on my shared linux hosting. Checked all requirements and all seems okay.

`Fatal error: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

My host says `imagick` is located in `/usr/local/bin/convert`. How do i correct this seeing i don't have access to the `php.ini` file? Please help

Comment: It looks like your web host told you the path to the `imagick` binary rather than the PHP extension. In any case, knowing the path is useless because, for obvious reasons, you need to be able to edit `php.ini` to load extensions.

Comment: @Chris As it stands, there is no way i could get access to the `php.ini` file as it's a shared host. Do you think there's another workaround to this?

Comment: There isn't really a workaround other than not using ImageMagick. You should probably just ask the hosting company to fix their PHP configuration so it loads ImageMagick from the right place though since the hosting provider clearly intends for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix i opted for now was to disable the check for startup error, though the error (server misconfiguration still happens) but the error is not shown anymore.

`error_reporting(0);
$f3=require('lib/base.php');`

See https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/pull/125